# linux curly brackets instead of if-then-else-fi do-done

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

Are curly brackets a suitable replacement for other constructs?

```
    [ -n "$TEST" ] && { XX='yes'; echo 'yes' } || { XX='no'; echo 'no' }
```

vs

```
    if [ -n "$TEST" ] ; then
       XX='yes'; echo 'yes'
    else 
       XX='no'; echo 'no'
    fi
```

another:

```
    for num in {000..2}; do echo "$num"; done
```

or

```
    for num in {000..2}; { echo "$num"; }
```

Comment: Arguably this would best be two separate questions -- we already have a Q&A knowledgebase entry for the "is A && B || C a ternary operator in bash?" question, but we can't consolidate with it because there's also the question about why the latter syntax works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the your first example, `A && B || C` and `if A; then B else C` have different behavior if `B` has a non-zero exit status.

```
[ -n "$TEST" ] && { echo this; false; } || { echo "this too?"; }
```

Your second example <strike>is</strike> should be a syntax error. Nothing in the documentation says you can replace the `do`/`done` pair with another compound command (which is what `{...}` is).

UPDATE: I'm told by the maintainer of `bash` that this is an undocumented feature that provides backwards compatibility with an undocumented feature in the original Bourne shell.

Comment: Good point on the first! this explain the reason for my question Thanks!. On the 'for' statement, works fine on Ubuntu and Debian.

Comment: So it does. I'm not sure I would rely on it, though; it appears to be an undocumented feature at best.

Comment: @fcm It works in bash and ksh, but not in any other shells. `dash` can't handle it, and that's default `/bin/sh` on Debian and Ubuntu.

Comment: I submitted a bug report to `bash`, if only to find out *why* it works. Seems like an undocumented shortcut, similar to the various short forms available in `zsh` (especially the one that looks like `for name ... [ in word ... ] term sublist` ).